# How do I use First() in LINQ but random?

Tags: c#, linq

In a list like this:

```
var colors = new List<string>{"green", "red", "blue", "black","purple"};
```

I can get the first value like this:

```
var color = colors.First(c => c.StartsWidth("b")); //This will return the string with "blue"
```

Bot how do I do it, if I want want a random value matching the conditions? For example something like this:

```
Debug.log(colors.RandomFirst(c => c.StartsWidth("b"))) // Prints out black
Debug.log(colors.RandomFirst(c => c.StartsWidth("b"))) // Prints out black
Debug.log(colors.RandomFirst(c => c.StartsWidth("b"))) // Prints out blue
Debug.log(colors.RandomFirst(c => c.StartsWidth("b"))) // Prints out black
```

As in if there are multiple entries in the list matching the condition, i want to pull one of them randomly.
It has (I need it to be) to be an inline solution.
Thank you.

Comment: In the real code, how long is the list from which to select a random value? I'm guessing it's pretty short.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Random ordering then:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var color = colors.Where(c => c.StartsWith("b"))
                  .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
                  .First();
```

The above generates a random number for each element and sorts the results by that number.

You propbably won't notice a random results if you have only 2 elements matching your condition. But you can try the below sample (using the extension method below):

```
var colors = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => "b" + i);

var rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(colors.RandomFirst(x => x.StartsWith("b"), rnd));
}
```

Output:

```
b23
b73
b27
b11
b8
```

You can create an extension method out of this called `RandomFirst`:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T RandomFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, 
                                                                                Random rnd)
    {
        return source.Where(predicate).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).First();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var color1 = colors.RandomFirst(x => x.StartsWith("b"), rnd);
var color2 = colors.RandomFirst(x => x.StartsWith("b"), rnd);
var color3 = colors.RandomFirst(x => x.StartsWith("b"), rnd);
```

### Optimization:

If you're worried about performance, you can try this optimized method (cuts the time to half for large lists):

```
public static T RandomFirstOptimized<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                        Func<T, bool> predicate, Random rnd)
{
    var matching = source.Where(predicate);

    int matchCount = matching.Count();
    if (matchCount == 0)
        matching.First(); // force the exception;

    return matching.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, matchCount));
}
```

Comment: 1. Better to use FirstOrDefault instead of First

Comment: Worth nothing that this will not work with some tools such as Entity Framework, other than that, good answer.

Comment: @Steve Yes i did. It returns a "Random" result starting with "b"

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev I followed what the OP used. If the OP wants to throw an exception if no item is found, then why would I want to change that ?

Comment: @user3185569 granted. Still I don't understand why a _OrderBy(x => 123472923)_ should return blue or black.

Comment: @Steve Because it generates a Random number for each element and sorts by that number.

Comment: That's fine for short sequences, but extremely expensive for long sequences. The OP only posits a short sequence, so this will probably be ok, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's `700ms` on average for `1,000,000` records in debug mode.

Comment: Compared to ~5ms for the same size if you use something like `colors.Skip(rnd.Next(colors.Count())).First()`... But obviously this is in only significant if the code is called multiple times, or for VERY large lists. The sorting starts to get exponentially slower for larger lists (10,0000 items takes over 7s for example)

Comment: @MatthewWatson without the predicate ?

Comment: @user3185569 I used `colors = colors.Where(x => x.StartsWith("b")).ToArray();` before the next step to include the predicate. Results for an array of 10,000,000 items was ~250ms for the O(N) solution, ~10s for the sorted array solution.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that takes `488ms` on my machine for `1,000,000` records.

Comment: Well, I think your method is fast enough for the OP's use - it's just for very large collections it would not be good (think 10,000,000 items or more). Timings I get for release build for 10,000,000 items is ~250ms for O(N) solution and ~8000ms for sorting solution. That's all I wanted to point out.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have already added another approach for large lists.

Answer (score 4):

In case you have `IList<T>` you could also write a tiny extension method to pick a random element:

```
static class IListExtensions
{
   private static Random _rnd = new Random();

   public static void PickRandom<T>(this IList<T> items) =>
       return items[_rnd.Next(items.Count)];
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var color = colors.Where(c => c.StartsWith("b")).ToList().PickRandom();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simple way for short sequences if you don't mind iterating the sequence twice:**

```
var randomItem = sequence.Skip(rng.Next(sequence.Count())).First();
```

For example (error handling elided for clarity):

```
var colors = new List<string> { "bronze", "green", "red", "blue", "black", "purple", "brown" };
var rng = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var sequence = colors.Where(c => c.StartsWith("b"));
    var randomItem = sequence.Skip(rng.Next(sequence.Count())).First();
    Console.WriteLine(randomItem);
}
```

This is an O(N) solution, but requires that the sequence is iterated once to get the count, then again to select a random item.

---

**More complex solution using Reservoir Sampling suitable for long sequences**

You can randomly select N items from a sequence of an unknown length in a single pass (O(N)) without resorting to expensive sorting, using a method known as [`Reservoir Sampling`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

You would especially want to use Reservoir Sampling when:

- The number of items to randomly choose from is large
- The number of items to randomly choose from is unknown in advance
- The number of items to randomly choose is small compared to the number of items to choose from

although you can use it for other situations too.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// This uses Reservoir Sampling to select <paramref name="n"/> items from a sequence of items of unknown length.
/// The sequence must contain at least <paramref name="n"/> items.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of items in the sequence from which to randomly choose.</typeparam>
/// <param name="items">The sequence of items from which to randomly choose.</param>
/// <param name="n">The number of items to randomly choose<paramref name="items"/>.</param>
/// <param name="rng">A random number generator.</param>
/// <returns>The randomly chosen items.</returns>

public static T[] RandomlySelectedItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int n, System.Random rng)
{
    var result = new T[n];
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (index < n)
        {
            result[count++] = item;
        }
        else
        {
            int r = rng.Next(0, index + 1);

            if (r < n)
                result[r] = item;
        }

        ++index;
    }

    if (index < n)
        throw new ArgumentException("Input sequence too short");

    return result;
}
```

For your case, you will need to pass `n` as 1, and you will receive an array of size 1.

You could use it like this (but note that this has no error checking, in the case that `colors.Where(c => c.StartsWith("b")` returns an empty sequence):

```
var colors = new List<string> { "green", "red", "blue", "black", "purple" };
var rng = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(RandomlySelectedItems(colors.Where(c => c.StartsWith("b")), 1, rng)[0]);
```

However, if you want to call this multiple times rather than just once, then you would be better off shuffling the array and accessing the first N items in the shuffled array. (It's hard to tell what your actual usage pattern will be from the question.)

Answer (score 3):

Another implementation is to extract all possible colors (*sample*) and take random one from them:

```
  // Simplest, but not thread safe
  private static Random random = new Random();  

  ...
  // All possible colors: [blue, black] 
  var sample = colors
    .Where(c => c.StartsWidth("b"))
    .ToArray();

  var color = sample[random.Next(sample.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created these two `RandomOrDefault` that are optimized to work on `IList`. One with predicate and one without it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a random element in the list
/// </summary>
public static TSource RandomOrDefault<TSource>(this IList<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null || source.Count == 0)
        return default;
    if (source.Count == 1)
        return source[0];
    var rand = new Random();

    return source[rand.Next(source.Count)];
}

/// <summary>
/// Get a random element in the list that satisfies a condition
/// </summary>
public static TSource RandomOrDefault<TSource>(this IList<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null || source.Count == 0)
        return default;
    if (source.Count == 1)
    {
        var first = source[0];
        if (predicate(first))
            return first;
        return default;
    }
    var matching = source.Where(predicate);

    int matchCount = matching.Count();
    if (matchCount == 0)
        return default;

    var rand = new Random();
    return matching.ElementAt(rand.Next(matchCount));
}
```